# Generate many addresses from one address line

Tags: string, vba, excel

So this is a problem I am stuck on and I would like to get some help/ideas on how can I solve this.

Problem is we are given a line of string which has data in this possible formats

Input sample #1:

```
100, 200, 300 Route 45
```

Output for #1

```
100, 200, 300 Route 45    
100 Route 45
200 Route 45
300 Route 45
```

Input sample #2

```
1000 Wildforest Drive; 2000 Wildridge Circle
```

Output for #2:

```
1000 Wildforest Drive; 2000 Wildridge Circle
1000 Wildforest Drive
2000 Wildridge Circle
```

Input sample #3

```
100-107 and 109 Grove Hill Drive, 400-418, 420, 422, 424, 426, 428, 430, 432, 434 and 436-441 Olive Branch Way
```

Output for #3

```
100-107 Grove Hill Drive and 109 Grove Hill Drive, 400-418, 420, 422, 424, 426, 428, 430, 432, 434 and 436-441 Olive Branch Way
100-107 Grove Hill Drive
109 Grove Hill Drive
400-418
420, 422, 424, 426, 428, 430, 432, 434 and 436-441 Olive Branch Way
422 Olive Branch Way
424 Olive Branch Way
426 Olive Branch Way
428 Olive Branch Way
430 Olive Branch Way
434 Olive Branch Way
436-411 Olive Branch Way
```

My attempt

```
Dim frowI As Long, i As Long, j As Long, frowO As Long, m As Long
Dim cet, fet, addR As String, stName As String

Sub Clean_Data()

frowI = INP.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To frowI

    frowO = frowO + 1
    addR = INP.Range("B" & i)
    OUT.Range("C" & frowO) = addR

    addR = Replace(addR, "and", ",")
    Debug.Print addR

    cet = Split(addR, ";")

    For j = LBound(cet) To UBound(cet)
        If InStr(cet(j), ",") > 0 Then
            fet = Split(cet(j), ",")

            For m = LBound(fet) To UBound(fet)
                fet(m) = Trim(fet(m))

                frowO = frowO + 1
                OUT.Range("C" & frowO) = fet(m) & " " & stName

            Next m

        End If
    Next j

Next i    

End Sub
```

Problem is I can't find a way to get the names of the street from the string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: cet = Split(addR, ";") here should it be comma rather than semi colon ?

Comment: Are they the only possible formats?

Comment: @ChrisHarper no first we should split by semi-colon then each element should be split by ,

Comment: I'd probably change `addR = Replace(addR, "and", ",")` to `addR = Replace(addR, " and ", " , ")` (put a space either side) to ensure that you don't change an address like "Grand Street" to "Gr, Street" accidentally.

Comment: @SJR Yes they are the only possible formats but the amount of numbers and names in the string can vary

Comment: @CLR Thanks will do that.

Comment: Should Input Sample #3 not have a semi-colon after `Grove Hill Drive`, not a comma?

Comment: No it shouldn't see that's the main issue We have to somehow differentiate between the two addresses

Comment: Just to make life complicated, is there any chance that a house 'number' could read '3a' ?

Comment: Might be a job for regular expressions.

Comment: I will take a look when I can as looks quite interesting, but probably someone else will already have solved.

Comment: @CLR no it can only contain number with or without hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the below, it uses Regular expressions to search the strings firstly for the street addresses and then secondly for the building number.

Someone might be able to come up with a better RegExp but this works in my tests.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Clean_Data()
    Dim RegExStreet As Object, RegExNo As Object, MatchesStreet As Object, MatchesNo As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nme As String, tmp As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c, no, street

    Set RegExStreet = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set RegExNo = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With RegExStreet
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([a-z]+\s[a-z]+\s[a-z]+|[a-z]+\s[a-z]+|[a-z]+\s\d+)"
    End With
    With RegExNo
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d\-|\d|\w\d)+"
    End With

    With INP
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
    End With

    i = 2
    For Each c In rng
        nme = vbNullString
        tmp = vbNullString

        Set MatchesStreet = RegExStreet.Execute(Replace(Replace(c.Value2, " and ", vbNullString, compare:=vbTextCompare), " et al", vbNullString, compare:=vbTextCompare))
        If MatchesStreet.Count > 0 Then
                tmp = c.Value2
                OUT.Cells(i, 3).Value2 = tmp
                i = i + 1
                For Each street In MatchesStreet
                    nme = street
                    Set MatchesNo = RegExNo.Execute(Left(tmp, InStr(1, tmp, street) - 1))
                    If MatchesNo.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each no In MatchesNo
                            OUT.Cells(i, 3).Value2 = no & " " & nme
                            i = i + 1
                        Next no
                    End If
                    tmp = Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - InStr(1, tmp, street))
                Next street
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Also, as a side note don't declare variables outside of subs unless you really need to. This can lead to errors

Comment: Thanks for your effort :) Although RegExNo.Execute(Left(tmp, InStr(1, tmp, street) - 1)) returns error because Instr sometimes returns 0 and it leads to -1 in third argument of Left

Comment: How? can you share your data structure? Anyway, this can be easily handled with an `If` statement. Can you give an example of your input that causes this error?

Comment: I added the file here which has my attempt your code and CLR's code as well https://www.dropbox.com/s/4eb5p7n7izpsf5z/AddressParse%20v1.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Just tried with your file. I can't get it to error with my code

Comment: Nope - removed that

Comment: @newguy which row is it on when it errors i.e. what does `tmp` hold?

Comment: c.row is 9 on error line. tmp is `ayne Avenue; 1105 and 1112 Oakland Avenue; 713 School Street` and street is `Oakl Avenue`

Comment: Found the error. I was replacing `and` so it changed the `Oakland` to `Oakl` and then tried to remove it. Have updated my code above to avoid this

Comment: Thanks it works awesome just two things 1. It should output first the whole string as it is and 2. I forgot to say that some house numbers have words in it like on row 47 in Input sheet. I know it's annoying but if you could make any changes in regex to identify that pattern it would be great. Thanks for your effort I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145209/discussion-between-tom-and-newguy).

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this, because it took a few minutes of my life to write. It's not my most elegant work. Tom's answer though is probably better and if I understood Regex better, would be the way I'd write it.

```
Dim fRowO As Long
Dim strNum As String, strAddr As String, wrdaddress As String
Dim cl, wrds, wrd, nums, n


fRowO = 1
For Each cl In Range("A1:A3")
    cl = Replace(cl, " and ", " , ")
    cl = Replace(cl, ";", ",")
    wrds = Split(cl, ",")
    strNum = ""
    strAddr = ""
    For Each wrd In wrds
        wrd = Trim(wrd)
        If LCase(wrd) Like "*[a-z]*" Then
            wrdaddress = Mid(wrd, InStr(wrd, " ") + 1, Len(wrd) - InStr(wrd, " ") + 1)
            strNum = strNum & Left(wrd, InStr(wrd, " ") - 1)
            strAddr = wrdaddress
            nums = Split(strNum, ";")
            For Each n In nums
                If n <> "" Then 
                    Cells(fRowO, 2) = n & " " & strAddr
                    fRowO = fRowO + 1
                End If
            Next
            strNum = ""
            strAddr = ""
        Else
            strNum = strNum & wrd & ";"
        End If
    Next
Next
```